# django custom database engine documentation

Tags: django, database

I'm making a django project where there is the need to use information from an ApiRest. To manage the information more easily I created classes to get the info and display it.

Since my classes aren't django models the relashionships between those and my database take a lot of work and will break with each change I make. So I want to use a custom database backend instead of the classes. But there I cant find any documentation on how it should be done.

Is there a place where I can find the documentation of how a database engine works in django?

I have already looked in the django docs but there is no article or section about database engines. Or I couldn't find it.

edit: added info

Comment: Make it more easy to use relations?

Comment: Have you started with the Django docs? And what do you mean by easier to use relations? Django has a robust system for relationships across quite a few RDBMS's

Comment: @dfundako yes, already looked inside the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking to do something similar - Creating a custom database engine using pyodbc.

I found

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkwZ1jG3XgA
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/media/2016/11/db.pdf and
https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2016/11/04/database-backends.html

as good documentation starting points.

Then I created https://pypi.org/project/django-filemaker-pyodbc/0.0.1/ after going through the documentation and reading through [django_pyodbc](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc)

Comment: Please update the YouTube URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkwZ1jG3XgA , above mentioned is not working!

Comment: @rohangoli - sorry about that - I misread your post - link updated to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkwZ1jG3XgA