# How to connect to 3rd party snowflake database using django?

Tags: django, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to create an engine to connect the snowflake db? On Configuring the

> settings.py

, it errors out with below message.

> Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
>       'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Comment: Check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610066/how-to-connect-to-snowflake-database-from-django-framework. There is an updated connector for Snowflake + Django

Answer (score 0):

Django officially supports these databases:

1. PostgreSQL
2. MariaDB
3. MySQL
4. Oracle
5. SQLite

And also these 3rd party databases:

1. CockroachDB
2. Firebird
3. IBM DB2
4. Microsoft SQL Server
5. ODBC

Since snowflakedb isn't in either of the two and you want to create an engine, I suggest creating your own custom database engine using pyodbc.
[django custom database engine documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801861/django-custom-database-engine-documentation)